# What is the difference between "internal", "external" and "application" errors in JSON-RPC 2.0?

Tags: json-rpc

There are three types of errors in the JSON-RPC 2.0 spec that I am having trouble fully disambiguating.

Looking at [section 5.1](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#error_object), I would like to bring attention to these three types:

1. Internal errors and
2. External errors, both described by the last two rows in the table.
3. Application defined errors, from the ending paragraph.

So, using the spec's wording, what exactly is the difference between a (1) "Internal JSON-RPC error" and a (2) "implementation-defined server-error"? I surmise that (3) is more concerned with errors concerning business-logic, but I'm not sure where types (1) and (2) end and (3) begins.